# NULL defaults not consistently working, & updates changing NULL to empty string Laravel4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, null

I have a number of fields which are NULL by default in MySQL. For example, in the code snips below, name is required and not null, but name_abbrev, email_general and description are all nullable and set to NULL by default in the database. But data entry via tables in Laravel mostly is not working. If I insert a row with only name and everything else left blank, name of course is entered correctly, and NULL is entered for email_general, but the other two nullable fields post the empty string instead of NULL. If I then update the row, say by changing the name, the update will also change the NULL for email_general to the empty string. And if I manually change the values in the database row for the nullable fields from empty string to NULL, when I update the row (still leaving all the empty fields empty), it changes all the NULL fields to empty string. I can't find anything I'm doing wrong. Why won't it enter NULL (except in one field which is coded exactly the same as the others), and why does update change even that field to the empty string?

Controller:

```
public function store() 
{
    $component = new Component;
    $component->name = Input::get('name');
    $component->name_abbrev = Input::get('name_abbrev');
    $component->email_general = Input::get('email_general');
    $component->description = Input::get('description'); ...
    $component->save();

    return Redirect::route('components.index');
}

public function update($id)
{
    $component = $this->component->find($id);
    $component->name = Input::get('name');
    $component->name_abbrev = Input::get('name_abbrev');
    $component->email_general = Input::get('email_general');
    $component->description = Input::get('description'); ...
    $component->save();

    return Redirect::route('components.index');
}
```

create.blade.php:

```
{{ Form::open(['route' => 'components.store']) }}
    <div class="required">
        {{ Form::label('name','Name:') }}
        {{ Form::text('name') }}
        {{ $errors->first('name') }}
    </div>      

    <div>
        {{ Form::label('name_abbrev','Abbreviation:') }}
        {{ Form::text('name_abbrev', NULL) }}
    </div>

    <div>
        {{ Form::label('email','General Email:') }}
        {{ Form::text('email',NULL) }}
    </div>

    <div>
        {{ Form::label('description','Description:') }}
        {{ Form::textarea('description',NULL,['size' => '26x3']) }}
    </div> ...

    <div>
        {{ Form::submit('Add New Component', array('class'=>'button')) }}
    </div>

{{ Form::close() }}
```

edit.blade.php:

```
{{ Form::model($component, array('method'=>'put','route'=>array('components.update', $component->id))) }}

    <div class="required">
        {{ Form::label('name','Name:') }}
        {{ Form::text('name') }}
        {{ $errors->first('name') }}
    </div>      

    <div>
        {{ Form::label('name_abbrev','Abbreviation:') }}
        {{ Form::text('name_abbrev', NULL) }}
    </div>

    <div>
        {{ Form::label('email_general','General Email:') }}
        {{ Form::text('email_general', NULL) }}
    </div

    <div>
        {{ Form::label('description','Description:') }}
        {{ Form::textarea('description',NULL,['size' => '26x3']) }}
    </div> ...

    <div>
        {{ Form::submit('Update Component', array('class'=>'button')) }}
    </div>

{{ Form::close() }}
```

Thanks very much! This should be easy, but for some reason, it's not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need null on some column, I would recommend you to use Mutators:

Laravel 3: http://three.laravel.com/docs/database/eloquent#getter-and-setter-methods

Laravel 4: http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators

So if the new value is an empty string ( ! $value ) overwrite it with NULL.

Comment: Thanks -- I've now learned how to use mutators, and it solved my problem perfectly!